# WPF XAML bind a DataGridTextColumn to a different than the source ObservableCollection item property

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

Excuse me if my question is answered already, more likely I don't use the correct search criteria.
Let say that I have two `ObservableCollections. The first one is the Questions:

```
private ObservableCollection<Question> _questions = new ObservableCollection<Question>();
    public ObservableCollection<Question> Questions
    {
        get { return _questions; }
        set
        {
            if (value != _questions)
            {
                _questions = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Questions");
            }
        }
    }
```

and the Question class looks like:

```
public class Question : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public Question()
    {

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private int _no = -1;
    public int No
    {
        get
        {
            return _no;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_no != value)
            {
                _no = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("No");
            }
        }
    }

    private int _corespondingQuestionNo = -1;
    public int CorespondingQuestionNo
    {
        get
        {
            return _corespondingQuestionNo;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_corespondingQuestionNo != value)
            {
                _corespondingQuestionNo = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CorespondingQuestionNo");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The second one is a collection of `QuestionElements`, which is pretty much the same, but it has `No` and a `string Title`.
The reason for having both is that depending on the language setting, we will show in the `DataGrid` the `Title`for each `CorespondingQuestionNo`at the proper language.
Currently my DataGrid looks like:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="questionsDataGrid"
              ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=casesDataGrid, Path=SelectedItem.Questions, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
              >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn 
            Binding="{Binding Path=No, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
            >
            </DataGridTextColumn>

        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

How should a DataGridTextColumn which shows the `Title` from `ObservableCollection<QuestionElements>` with No == `CorespondingQuestionNo` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot map the binding to another collection based on the `No` property in pure XAML. You will have to write some code somewhere.

What you should do is to create a `QuestionViewModel` class that contains all properties that you want to bind to, i.e. you should merge the `Question` and `QuestionElements` types together into one common view model type `T` and then bind to an `ObservableCollection<T>`. This is that view models are used for after all.